# pytest how do I add to metadata

Tags: python, pytest

when I run my `pytests`, I like to add variables like `browser`, `browserVersion` and `driverversion` to metadata so they are picked up by the `pytest-html` plugin:

```
metadata: {'Python': '3.7.4', 'Platform': 'Windows-10-10.0.18362-SP0',\
'Packages': {'pytest': '5.0.1', 'py': '1.8.0', 'pluggy': '0.12.0'}, \
'Plugins': {'base-url': '1.4.1', 'clarity': '0.2.0a1', 'html': '1.22.0', \
'metadata': '1.8.0', 'mock': '1.10.4', 'variables': '1.7.1'}, \
'JAVA_HOME': 'C:\\Program Files\\AdoptOpenJDK\\jdk-8.0.212.03-hotspot\\', 'Base URL': ''}
```

How can I add like selenium webdriver capabilities to metadata:

```
webdriver:chrome, capabilities:{'acceptInsecureCerts': False,\
'browserName': 'chrome', 'browserVersion': '76.0.3809.100', \
'chrome':  {'chromedriverVersion': '76.0.3809.126 (d80a294506b4c9d18015e755cee48f953ddc3f2f-refs/branch-heads/3809@{#1024})}'
```

I have a `pytest.fixture` for `webdriver` and `WEBDRIVER` is an environment variable
that control the browser, but they do not show up in metadata.

I can add statics and `env-vars` with this hook in `conftest.py`, but driver is not initialized, it is set up in its own fixture, how can I make sure this fixture is run after my `wd` fixture (which set up global driver). You are not allowed to add fixtures to functions in `conftest.py`:

```
@pytest.mark.optionalhook
def pytest_metadata(metadata):
    global driver
    if driver:
        metadata['browserName'] = driver.capabilities['browserName']
        metadata['browserVersion'] = driver.capabilities['browserName']
        if driver.capabilities.get('chrome'):
            metadata['chromedriverVersion'] = driver.capabilities['chrome']['chromedriverVersion']
    else:
        metadata['drivererror'] = "driver not initialized"
```

Comment: A workaround it so move setup of webdriver into `pytest_metadata()`and drop my entire webdriver setup fixture. Not very elegant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the metadata dict in fixtures and tests via the `config._metadata` attribute, for example

```
@pytest.fixture(scope='session')
def driver():
    return webdriver.Chrome()


@pytest.fixture(autouse=True, scope='session')
def store_driver_info(request, driver):
    request.config._metadata['browserName'] = driver.capabilities['browserName']


def test_browser_name(request, driver):
    assert request.config._metadata['browserName'] == driver.capabilities['browserName']
```

Comment: `autouse=True` and using the `request autofixture (not `config`) and adding it all into the driver (I called it `wd`) was the solution. Thanks